Audio Distortion in Ubuntu 24.10
I have installed 24.10 in my Lenovo Ideapad 3, I have this cracking sound when playing youtube, how can I fix this?
In headphones and bluetooth are all okay, just in the built-in speakers
$ ps -e | grep pipewire
   2377 ?        00:00:00 pipewire
   2379 ?        00:00:00 pipewire
   2386 ?        00:00:00 pipewire-pulse
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-15 03:44:16 PST; 11min ago
 Invocation: e30e3ff9a80546838b368aa324ae702e
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 2377 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18143)
     Memory: 7M (peak: 9.2M)
        CPU: 267ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewi>
             └─2377 /usr/bin/pipewire

Oct 15 03:44:16 cheesecake systemd[2354]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire M>


